# Scrapy how to handle pound sign?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Python and Scrapy and I'm trying to test if a string (extracted using an xpath selector) contains the pound symbol (british currency - £).

At the top of my source file I have specified the encoding:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

and I'm performing this test:

```
if '£' in price:
...
```

However I'm getting an error exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2.

If I change the test to

```
price = price.encode('utf-8')
if '£' in price:
...
```

It works. Can someone explain why the price.encode() call is necessary, I understood that Scrapy returns unicode strings anyway. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# these have different types:
if some_string in some_unicode_object
```

Doing this is equivalent to writing:

```
# convert the first argument so we can do the `in`
if some_string.decode('ascii') in some_unicode_object
```

So in your example:

```
if '£' in price:
#  ^string ^unicode
```

You're calling `'£'.encode('ascii')`, which fails because it isn't an ASCII bytestring.

A better way of writing this would be:

```
if u'£' in price:
```

alternatively, you may want to write [`from __future__ import unicode_literals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html).

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense